# Nuget, portable library and WinRT appx: Payload contains two or more files with the same destination path

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, nuget, portable-class-library, appx

1. Create new Windows 8 application `App1`
2. Add `ClassLibrary1` Windows 8 class library project to solution
3. Add `PortableClassLibrary1` portable class library targeting Windows 8 and Windows Phone 7.5 to a solution
4. Reference `HttpClient` nuget package in `ClassLibrary1`
5. Reference `HttpClient` nuget package in `PortableClassLibrary1`
6. Reference both `ClassLibrary1` and `PortableClassLibrary1`
7. Compile solution

You get an error at .appx package stage

```
Payload contains two or more files with the same destination path 'System.Net.Http.Primitives.dll'. 
Source files: 
\Projects\App1\PortableClassLibrary1\bin\Debug\System.Net.Http.Primitives.dll
\Projects\App1\packages\Microsoft.Net.Http.2.2.13\lib\win8\System.Net.Http.Primitives.dll
```

Please note the same error is reproduced if you reference any nuget package featuring both win8 and portable blends of assemblies.

What is expected:
Most specific version of a library (win8 one) is packaged into .appx and portable version is ignored

Any ideas on how to cheat appx packager and build this kind of Windows 8 projects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to this, you should be getting warnings similar to:

> All projects referencing ClassLibrary1.csproj must install nuget
>   package Microsoft.Bcl.Build. For more information, see
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=317569.

This is indicating a problem. Basically, the short of it, you should be installing HttpClient.Compression into all projects. MSBuild/AppX packaging doesn't know which binary to deploy between the portable library and store library project (they have different APIs & versions). Installing the package into the application, tells it.

Answer (score 9):

It looks like the solution described here works: http://cyanbyfuchsia.wordpress.com/2013/05/03/payload-contains-two-or-more-files-with-the-same-destination-path/

Basically, you must set "Copy local" to false in the WinRT project that is referenced from the main app.

Comment: The approach I ended up taking was to add the NuGet package to the main application, then make sure that for all of the referenced libraries, "Copy local" was set to false on the references. So the application project is the "master" of including those files. I also had warnings telling me to install Microsoft.Bcl.Build, but doing that didn't help.

Comment: I was getting this error because my UnitTesting Project has an Assets folder as well. Since unit tests don't need these assets (logos, icons, etc.) I just deleted them.

Answer (score 0):

I had such issue **too**. It was **because** I shared one of my solution between projects. I had to rename the solution, because the name was all the same like one of the projects. After renaming I had this problem.

I **fixed** it by: right click on solution I renamed and used both projects, then properties, then use same name in the **assembly name** like solution name.